# How to add dynamic array to RecycleView

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an activity that I'm trying to get data from API and show the list there but I cannot get my data in the `adapter`.

## Code

`MainActivity.kt`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        categories.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        categories.adapter = CategoriesAdapter(//what should be here?)
    }
    
    // api code
    private fun callAPIDemo(textView: TextView) {
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "https://example.com/api/isp/categories"
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                val jsonArray = JSONArray(response)
                val list: MutableList<Category> = ArrayList()
                for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                    val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    list.add(parseData(jsonObject))
                }
                // here you will have the complete list of data in your "list" variable
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "That didn't work!" })
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest)
    }
    // parsing data
    private fun parseData(jsonObject: JSONObject): Category {
        var listingObject = Category(
            jsonObject.getString("name"),
            jsonObject.getString("slug"),
            jsonObject.getString("image")
        )
        return listingObject
    }
    //
```

`CategoriesAdapter.kt`

```
class CategoriesAdapter(val categories : ArrayList<Category>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.categories_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return categories.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textView.text = categories.get(position).name
        holder.textViewSlug.text = categories.get(position).slug

        //hardcoding the image, just for simplicity, you can set this also from data list same as above
        //holder.aImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)

        //here is the image setup by using glide
        Glide.with(holder.aImage.context).load(categories.get(position).image).into(holder.aImage)
    }


    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var textView: TextView
        var textViewSlug: TextView
        var aImage: ImageView

        init {
            textViewSlug = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_slug)
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_name)
            aImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.a_image)

        }
    }

}
```

`Category.kt`

```
data class Category(
    val name: String,
    val slug: String,
    val image: String
)
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`categries_row.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/a_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/a_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/a_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a_image" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_slug"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text_name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

## Question

what should I put in `categories.adapter = CategoriesAdapter(//what should be here?)` in my `MainActivity.kt` file?

Comment: why dont your initialize recyclerview with adapter and you are not finding any recyclerview in mainactivity

Comment: @sashabeliy `categories` is my `recycleView` as i have recycleview with id of `categories` in my `activity_main.xml` when ever i call `categories` it means `recycleView` as you can see i have `categories.adapter()` that means `RecycleView.adapter()`

Comment: you have to find your recyclerview by using findviewById I posted that code please check

Comment: and you have to pass your json response to recyclerview in order pass you have to find recyclerview in mainactivity check my answer let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
         recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.categories)

        categories.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        categories.adapter = CategoriesAdapter(this)
    }
// api code
private fun callAPIDemo(textView: TextView) {
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val url = "https://example.com/api/isp/categories"
    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            val jsonArray = JSONArray(response)
            val list: MutableList<Category> = ArrayList()
            for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                list.add(parseData(jsonObject))
            }
            // here you will have the complete list of data in your "list" variable
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "That didn't work!" })
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}
// parsing data
private fun parseData(jsonObject: JSONObject): Category {
    var listingObject = Category(
        jsonObject.getString("name"),
        jsonObject.getString("slug"),
        jsonObject.getString("image")
    )
    return listingObject
}
//
```

Comment: `recyclerView =` is red and i cannot find reference for `applicationContext` in your code

Comment: private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null put this code above onCreate check my code which I wrote in answer carefully

Comment: that fixed `recyclerView` how about `applicationContext`?

Comment: val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
                    categories?.layoutManager = layoutManager something like this

Comment: would you mind update your answer please? it's a bit confusing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207447/discussion-between-sashabeliy-and-mafortis).